# Convert column values to a sequence in a specific order using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have few products to which I want to assign a Ref_id. I am getting these products from a product table like below :

```
val products=ProductDF.select("key").distinct()
```

If I receive any below product order should be as given in the table :

[image]

```
val seqDF = Seq(("Service",0),("S-Product",1),("Speed Product",2),("Mobile Plan Small",3),("Small Product",4),("Day Product",5)).toDF("key", "ref_id")
```

If any other product comes , I should be appending the Ref-id after 4 as per below example:

[image]

```
val seqDF = Seq(("Service",0),("S-Product",1),("Speed Product",2),("Small Product",3),("Day Product",4),("New Product-1",5),("New Product2",6)).toDF("key", "ref_id")
```

Else If any product missed from the first five Products , Ref ID should be adjusted as below: for eg : Small Product is deleted here

[image: Key Ref_id Service 0 S-Product 1 Speed Product 2 Day Product 3 New Product-1 4 New Product-2 5]

```
val seqDF = Seq(("Service",0),("S-Product",1),("Speed Product",2),("Day Product",3),("New Product-1",4),("New Product-2",5)).toDF("key", "ref_id")
```

My code was like this for first 5 products , Let me know how to best handle additions and deletions as per above example and assign a Ref_id:

val seqDF = Seq(("Service",0),("S-Product",1),("Speed Product",2),("Small Product",3),("Day Product",4)).toDF("key", "ref_id")

Comment: Can you please remove the images and add the data as text?

Comment: What do you mean by handle addition and deletions? how do toy add and delete data to dataframe ?

Comment: sure I will add images and add text , give me few minutes

Comment: @koiralo I have added the code sample in the seqDF, below every image . Does it look fine to you now ? 
By addition , I mean if additional products apart from Image one come then take maximum of ref id and assign them
I have shown addition example in Image-2
and deletion example in Image-3

Comment: But how does the new data comes in ?

Comment: I'm taking the distinct product from a product table

Comment: @koiralo My Job runs daily , so Day 1 - I can have 2 products, Day 2 - additional products can come or existing onces gets deleted. So basically product tables gets updated everyday and I take distinct values of products. ..... I edited the question as well to make things clear

Comment: I didn't get it, may be better to add input data rather than dataframe, May be if it runs daily, add the sample data you receive 1st day and on second day and expected output

Comment: I think you have to use delta file format. By using this you can add, remove and update. This is refernence link https://www.learningjournal.guru/article/distributed-architecture/why-delta-lake-for-apache-spark/    or https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html